# How to allow updates to input without updating props in React?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to allow a user to enter changes in an input field without propagating them to the parent. I did this by returning out of the `onChange` function whenever I don't want to propagate. However this seems to undo the character I typed.

Here is a use case. I have a number field. I want to trigger `onChange` on parent when there is a number entered, but ignore "." and ","s (`formatters.staticToFloat` removes them).

```js
export default class NumberField extends React.Component {
  render () {
    var props = this.props;

    var format = props.formatter || formatters.number;
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{props.inputLabel}</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name={props.name}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
          value={!_.isUndefined(props.value) ? format(props.value) : null}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onChange (e) {
    var numValue = formatters.stringToFloat(e.target.value);
    //they added a . or , we don't propagate change
    if (this.props.value === numValue) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange({
        value: numValue,
        valid: validation.isValid(numValue, this.props.validation)
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: What if the user types '123.'? Do you want the input field to display '123.' (including the ".")? Or just the numbers typed? My answer below is solution to display only the formatted value, so any typed "." etc are completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best way I've come up with is maintaining a separate `formattedValue` state that only gets set when I want to override the default formatting. It works, but seems like a super dirty solution.

```js
export default class NumberField extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      formattedValue: null
    };
  }

  render () {
    var props = this.props;
    var state = this.state;
    var format = props.formatter || formatters.number;
    var inputValue = state.formattedValue || (
      !_.isUndefined(props.value) ?
        format(props.value) :
        null
      );
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{props.inputLabel}</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name={props.name}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
          value={inputValue}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onChange (e) {
    var numValue = formatters.stringToFloat(e.target.value);
    //they added a . or , we don't propagate change
    if (this.props.value === numValue) {
      this.setState({
        formattedValue: e.target.value
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        formattedValue: null
      });
    }

    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange({
        value: numValue,
        valid: validation.isValid(numValue, this.props.validation)
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case for using state to store the formatted value inside the component, and use a special variant of setState with a callback.

- all user input (including . and ,) is put in state and rendered in input field back to user.
- only when the format is correct, the parent `onChange()` is called.

The parent may actually do a re-render triggered by the  `onChange()` call. Therefore, we need to make sure that the last entered character is updated in state, and only after that the parent's `onChange()` will be called.

Your component would look like as follows:

```
export default class NumberField extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: !_.isUndefined(props.value) ? 
        props.formatter ? props.formatter(props.value).toString() : formatters.number(props.value).toString() 
        : null;
    };
  }

  render () {
    var props = this.props;
    var state = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{props.inputLabel}</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name={props.name}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
          value={state.value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onChange (e) {
    var numValue = formatters.stringToFloat(e.target.value);
    // if numValue is different from current state
    // then it must be an OK update, 
    // so we update state AND call parent if function exists
    if (numValue.toString() != this.state.value) {
      this.setState({
        value: numValue
      },
      this.callParent // here is the magic: we pass a callback, to be  called after state update and after re-render
      );
    } else {
     // otherwise we only update state (to display invalid character)
      this.setState({
        value: numValue
      });
    }
  }

  callParent() {
    // state is updated and component has re-rendered when this is called
    // so we can use state.value to inform parent
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange({
        value: this.state.value,
        valid: validation.isValid(this.state.value, this.props.validation)
      });
    }    
  }
};
```

This may be a bit of overkill: you keep a state (formatted value) that you also communicate to the parent. If your parent ALWAYS passes down the newly forwarded input, then you could make your component a lot simpler:
No state, but simply re-render based on props.

You only really need state if the value presented to the user in the input field can deviate from what you communicate to parent.